# uikit slider navigation visibility and creation?

Tags: html, css, getuikit

How do you make the navigation arrows of the Uikit slider always visible or make navigation circles below the slider? Thanks a lot to all of you people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For navigation arrows always visible, include slidenav component css file and add simple css to your own style.

```
.uk-slidenav-position .uk-slidenav {
    display: block;
}
```

Using dotnav under slideshow is also possible, just place it after div with slideshow, it can be anywhere it fits you. `data-uk-slideshow-item` will connect it with your slideshow https://getuikit.com/docs/slideshow.html#navigations